# First time changing switches and outlets (receptacles). Anything special I should know?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle, usa, canonical

I am replacing a bunch of switches and receptacles in my house.

While I understand the basics, this is pretty much my first electrical project, and I figure there must be some hidden "gotchas" or surprises that people run in to when doing this.

Any advice on what to watch out for?

Comment: Do you have copper or aluminum conductor in the wires for the 120 V circuits?

Comment: @JimStewart Harper's idea was to create a question with answers to cover common issues - he wrote about receptacle tabs, GFCIs (the basics) and 3-way/4-way; I wrote about smart switches - you can add an answer about aluminum wiring.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, aside from checking with a tester to make sure the circuit is *actually* off... there are several subtle issues that frequently catch novices.

Don't remove screws all the way - they are captive. After some distance they will start getting stiff. Stop there, don't force them.

### Torque screwdriver

Unless you're using the new "lever-nut" style receptacles or the dreaded backstabs, you need to torque the receptacle screws if they specify a torque.  This requires a torque screwdriver; a recent requirement in NEC 2014 due to recent science that says it matters. (and some other field testing at trade shows that revealed pro electricians can't torque "by feel" any more accurately than their spouse, apprentice or other traveling companion.)

### Receptacles - Tabs

Most common North American style receptacles have 2 sockets and 2 attachment screws on each hot and neutral side.  Between the screws is a "tab" of metal that can be flexed back and forth and snapped off.

**Check the tabs**.  If your old receptacle has any tab(s) broken off, you must break them off on the new receptacle.

[image]

*There's your tab. This [$1 outlet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Residential-Grade-Grounding-Duplex-Outlet-Ivory-R51-05320-00I/100044028) was ruined, by [soldering (!)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/130790/repairing-electrical-outlet-fin) and removing the screws.*

If you break one off by accident, and the receptacle is valuable, that's fixable.

On receptacles, brass screws are for hot and silver wires are for neutral.

### Broken tabs and GFCIs, USB or other specialty outlets

If your have an outlet with tab broken, and you are trying to replace it with a GFCI, USB or other specialty outlet, this is a specialty task. You'll need more research. Don't just cram the wires on anyway!

### GFCI receptacles otherwise

Take care to distinguish LINE from LOAD.

If you are replacing a plain outlet with GFCI, leave the warning tape on, and hook up only the LINE terminals (cap off spare wires). Power up the circuit and test the GFCI.  After it works, shut off the breaker and consider adding wires to LOAD *if you want to use this GFCI to protect that downstream part of the circuit, which is a cost-saver if you know what you're doing*. Otherwise, add those wires to LINE. Most GFCIs support [screw-to-clamp](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/) for 2 wires per screw; just read the instructions.

### Switches - 3-way (UK: 2-way)

Anytime you see 3 or more screws (besides ground), watch out.   3-way switches are tricky, because **screw position** and **wire colors** are ***meaningless*** - they vary on every switch.  The color of the screws matters.  (or if uncolored: labeling).

- One screw  will be black, and is called **"common"**.
- The two other screws are brass colored, and are **"travelers"**.

I'm a big fan of buying a 5-pack of colored tape, and marking both travelers with yellow tape.  (for a second 3-way: blue tape). This makes it a lot easier to tell what's going on in a busy box.  There is no need to distinguish them from each other, so use the same color.  Two same-colored wires in the same cable tells an experienced person these are travelers.

Marking is helpful because the *native* wire colors of travelers mean nothing. I've seen 3-way circuits *in a how-to guide* where 3 different pairs of colors were used in the same 3-way loop!

### 4-way (UK: 3-way)

These switches have 2 brass and 2 black screws.   Two pairs of travelers attach.  One pair of travelers attach to the brass screws.  The other pair of travelers attach to black.  In most cases, it's easy to group them in pairs - any pair of travelers is always in the same cable or conduit.  Just make sure that is so.

For marking, I typically mark all 4 travelers yellow, since you can easily see the grouping by looking at the cables.

Comment: To add to this, my phone's camera has saved me numerous times. Take a few pictures of each box and receptacle after removing it. Also, ensure power is off. For a few dollars, a touch-less wire tester is priceless. I got one after I thought I had turned off all power to a box, but ended up finding out the hard way that I had not...

Comment: Another vote for a non-contact voltage tester. One will often find two different circuits in the same junction box. Be sure that you know how to recognize aluminum (versus copper) wiring -- that's a whole different ball of flammable fun if you get it wrong. Also know how to recognize knob and tube wiring -- it has its own challenges.

Comment: If you're changing 2 prong outlets to 3 prong, you either need a ground or a GFCI (with a warning label) to be compliant.

Comment: If the person before you didn't leave much wire length, you can add a pigtail (same wire gauge) to get a bit of breathing room. This isn't a universally held opinion, but I really like the "Ideal In-Sure Push-In Wire Connector" (N. America only; Wago makes EU equivalents) for tight connections. Be aware that you can overload a box with too many connectors. (Google 'box fill calculations'.)

Comment: The question isn't "tell me everything that could possibly be said about about changing receptacles, including all the basics, so the hidden gotchas get buried in a wall of text".

Comment: I think I'd put strange old wire/ surprisingly hot jboxes/ etc into the 'gotcha' category, but feel free to delete comments as you see fit. You've done a good job with your headings to delineate... maybe that helps the wall of text problem.

Answer (score 13):

### Safety First

Always:

- It is very important that anything permanently installed - lights, receptacles, switches, etc. - be properly *listed* for your area. In the USA, this normally means [UL listing](https://www.ul.com/). Beware of other marks - CE and many other marks (if legitimate!) do not actually mean the device was *tested* to meet verify that it meets safety requirements.
- Check power before working on switches & receptacles. Turn off power using the method you *think* is correct - breaker or fuse - and then check again using a non-contact tester. If it lights up, you may have accidentally used the wrong breaker or fuse, or you may have more serious problems such as a circuit that is connected to two breakers.

### Smart Switches

Ordinary toggle switches are often replaced because they wear out or for decorative reasons. Straight replacement with an equivalent "dumb" switch is normally very easy as explained in Harper's answer.

However, if you are installing a timer, WiFi controlled switch or other **smart** switch, there is a potentially big complication: **neutral**

A smart switch needs to get power to run the electronics that make it smart. There are three ways that a smart switch can power itself:

#### Neutral Wire

The neutral wire is the simplest to design and, IMHO, the most reliable method. The switch effectively operates as a device (typically a very, very small computer) with one of the outputs being control of power to a light or other device.

The problem is that a "dumb" switch does not use neutral. Until recently, a typical switch box did not necessarily include a neutral. In some cases, that is easy to fix as the neutral is close by. In other cases, particularly **switch loops**, it is not so easy to fix. Current code in most areas **requires** a neutral in the switch box unless the wires are run in conduit (relatively easy to add a neutral) or certain other special cases.  But if you have an older house, adding a neutral may be a significant added expense (time and money) to what otherwise would seem like a simple smart switch installation. Keep in mind that if your wires are run in cables (e.g., 12/2 or 14/2 - black, white and ground), you can't simply "add a neutral" - you must replace the entire cable.

#### Trickle current even when "off"

This is a handy solution, when it works. This generally works well with incandescent bulbs - the little bit of current doesn't cause a noticeable glow in the light bulbs and everything works fine. However, with LED lights, often a very little bit of current is all that is needed to make it up. Even worse, some LED lights, particularly if they are not designed to work with a dimmer, will flash instead of glowing dimly, which is really annoying.

#### Ground Wire

There are some switches which will use the ground as the return path for the current that powers the electronics. This is against the general policy of "nothing goes on ground except in an emergency", but it is allowed within certain limits regarding the amount of current and other design factors.

If you don't have neutral easily accessible in your switch boxes then do some research before buying any smart switches. The instruction manuals will usually make it clear whether neutral is needed or not, though it can be a little trickier figuring out how a switch that does **not** use neutral actually gets power.

Comment: So if you are updating a older switch to a light that turns out to be a switch loop with only a 14/2 romex going into the switch box you need to replace that cable introduce a new cable to introduce a neutral wire? Do a lot of electricians go this route when upgrading recepticles and switches for home owners? Seems like a lot of drywall repair.

Comment: As I understand it, if you are replacing an existing switch then the "neutral required" rule does not apply. Which means that if you have a no-neutral switch loop then you either don't get a smart switch or you find one that doesn't need neutral. Not so much of an issue for receptacles - the change on receptacles is to add ground, and sometimes it is already lurking in the background (literally), plus you can retrofit ground via a different path (sometimes practical, sometimes not) plus you can use GFCI in lieu of ground.

Answer (score 9):

The wrap direction of the wire on the screw terminal matters. It needs to follow the clockwise tightening, not go against it. Otherwise, the wire will tend to slip out of contact as you tighten it, possibly giving a bad connection.

Also realize that the [NEC book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Electrical_Code) is something like an inch thick, and that all those rules were written in fire. Are you sure you want to proceed using only the knowledge you get from these few answers instead?