# Only one side of Tandem Circuit lost power at outlets

Tags: circuit-breaker

Replaced all outlets in a room that was part of a 15amp tandem circuit breaker. One circuit had a room that has dual outlets with a switch controlling the  top outlet on each. Turned both breakers off on the tandem circuit breaker. Did the outlet switching and when I turned it back on the outlets on the other tandem circuit stopped working. All I did was to turn the breaker off and back on. Tested for power at the panel and the tandem circuit breaker is live on both sides. Room with other circuit outlets were dead. Room with switched outlets works fine

Comment: When you say "tandem" do you mean "2-pole" whose handles are tied together and must be tripped together?  **Also, did any of the old outlets have their [tabs broken off](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/168565/47125)?**

Comment: It was the circuit breaker.....Inspection revealed a loose wire Reconnected and problem solved Murphys law!