# How should I connect a new outlet with two pairs of wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I have a kitchen outlet that stopped working. I"m in the process of replacing it. I've discarded the old outlet. I purchased a Hubbell duplex receptacle. It has brass screws on the left side with a split circuit tab between them and 2 silver screws with a split circuit tab on the right side.

Do I wire the 2 black wires onto  the brass screws and the two white wires onto the silver screws? My test light indicated that only 1 of the black wires is hot.

Comment: Welcome, James. I get the impression that you are new to house wiring. There are some fundamentals that are important for safety, such as how to create and properly use a wire loop for the screws. I suggest doing some reading of a good how-to book before going further. There's risk involved here.

Comment: I believe we have a [FAQ for that](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul).  Was the old outlet not connected that way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, wire the black wires to the brass screws and the whites to the silver screws. The black wire that is not hot is feeding a receptacle downstream and being fed by the wire that is hot via the receptacle. Do not remove the tabs on the outlet in this case.

If it's a direct replacement, when in doubt wire the new one the same as the old one and you'll be fine. If you have any doubts as to the connection, post up a few pics.

Comment: I always like to pigtail these outlets.  Good part about going to the screws ( not the backstabs)+