# Why does my breaker keep tripping

Tags: electrical

I changed an outlet that is controlled by a 3way switch and now my breaker keeps tripping the switch has a red,black and white wire the black is hot and the outlet has two black and two white wires everything worked fine until I changed the outlet

Comment: Does it trip instantly or does the breaker hold for a while before tripping? Does it trip when the switch is off or only when it is on?

Comment: Its common for a switched outlet to only be half switched and the connected tabs on the side of the outlet are broken off to support this.  Do you have the old outlet?  Are the connecting tabs broken?  Did you change any of the switch wiring?  Please edit any answers into your question.

Comment: Does our [advice on changing outlets](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul) give you any help?

Comment: Can you post photos of the outlet, the wiring in the back of the outlet box, and the wiring in the back of the switch box please?