# Outlet one hot wire, one not

Tags: electrical

I have two black (hot) and two white (neutral) and a ground. One black is hot with breaker on and the other is not. What is the likely cause?

Comment: One is controlled by a wall switch?

Comment: What prompted you to ask this question? Are you replacing a receptacle, and if so, are you replacing it with a GFCI?

Comment: This needs more detail. Are the 2 cables in the same box in the wall? Is this a switch, an outlet, or a fixture?

Comment: One brings power to the box the other is a traveler that once hooked up takes power to another outlet

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail to answer properly. Is this a switch box? an outlet box?  What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The very fact that you separated them for testing is why one is not hot.

Circuits (coming off a breaker) power more than one outlet.

Hot and neutral enter the box on one cable.  To get to the next outlet, they exit the box on another cable.  Each wire has a black and white, and in most cases black=hot.

If you disconnet the two wires from each other, one will be connected to the breaker.  The other will be disconnected from the breaker *because you disconnected it*.

It's common to use a receptacle itself as a splicing point.  The recep has 2 screws that are connected to each other *and to the socket slots).  The 2 screws can be used to splice 2 wires to each other (and the socket slots of course).

This doesn't always work, receptacles [have "tabs"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul).

If you don't like the idea of using a receptacle as a splice, then look up "pigtailing".