# Electrical Outlet/Switch Cover Vanity Plate Screw Issues

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle, screws, paint-removal

I am taking the time to update all of my outlets and switches in my home since they are 14+ years old or older and most of them are the *METALLIC* and **NOT NYLON** and have the vanity/cover plate entirely painted over and its taking me about 20 minutes of futile finagling of unscrewing the slotted screws (slots caked to the brim with paint) on **EACH OUTLET/SWITCH**, *my issue and question to you awesome Goobers is*,

***Is there a safe, fast and efficient method to remove these paint filled vanity/cover plate slotted screws from the outlets and switches ?***

Thank you in Advanced !!

Comment: I find that angling the screwdriver with a corner of the tip at one end of the slot and giving it a _light_ tap with a small hammer usually clears the slot quickly. It may need a second pass from the opposite end to clear sufficiently.

Comment: Be sure to read [our "what to watch out for" article](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul) so you avoid *those* known problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t's the slot in the head of the plate screw that makes unscrewing the screws a hassle! I always curse slot headed screws when I encounter them!

The trick to use that makes the screws unscrew with no problems is to clean out the slot of the screw head. Using a utility knife slice through the dried paint that is clogging the slot. It may take a couple of passes with the knife blade, but it will clear the paint quickly.

Pay attention to your digits (fingers) location when slicing.

The screwdriver tip now has a deeper straighter slot to turn against. No more slipping.

Comment: what do you mean by "digits location"

Comment: @Alyosha_Karamazov digits = fingers in this case

Comment: @Alyosha_Karamazov- yes, what 3PhaseEel said. (I updated my answer to be more clear.)

Comment: Note, @Alyosha_Karamazov, that this technique (or simply scraping with a screwdriver, as suggested in a comment on your question) will work on _any_ type of screw head that's been filled with paint, dirt or other gloop making it difficult to unscrew. Slotted screws are _easier_ to clean out, but that's about the only advantage to them.

Comment: Dig paint out of a Philips or Torx screw sometime, and you'll be singing the praises of slotted...