# Switching old light switches with new ones

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I am trying to replace my old side by side light switches with new rocker switches. The old switches were single pole, had 2 black wires coming in from the wall and one going in between the switches. The first wire was going to the bottom gold screw on the switches and the second was attached to the top push in contact on the back of the switches. I tried changing them out but now they do not work at all. Not sure what I'm missing here. Help!

Comment: Read [our Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul) on that.  Be particularly wary of switches with 3 screws besides ground.  However it sounds like you have 2 wires going to one side of the switch, which is another problem.

Comment: Can you include a few pictures of the switch box and can you restore it to how it was before you disassembled everything?

Answer (score 1):

The wire going between the switches is the hot wire. Verify you still have a hot as if this is missing none of the switches will work.