# Funky Wiring for Half Hot Receptacle in Bedroom

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I am in the process of upgrading switches and receptacles in an older home (DIYer). I love learning electrical, but I am stumped on the wiring for a circuit with a half hot outlet. Wondering if a kind soul might be able to point me in the right direction.

Basically, I replaced old receptacles and switches with Decora units, connecting the wires the same way they were originally. I broke off the tab on the half hot outlet (Outlet A in the diagram).

There was one outlet that was a switched outlet.

After swapping everything out, the receptacle that was previously half hot does not operate as expected, and stays on all the time.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
[image: Half Hot Wiring]

Comment: `receptacle that was previously half hot does not operate as expected` ... which one is that?

Comment: `A` is wrong ... the wall switch is connected between hot and neutral

Comment: @jsotola there is no wall switch at A. The wall switch is at C. You're looking at a wire nut, graphically. The connection to the switch loop is at B, and correctly (for a switch loop) connects the always-hot to white and the switched hot to black.

Comment: @jsotola because the switch loop is coming out of `B`.  The /2 cables coming into `A` and `D` are simply onward wiring to other outlets, and power source. (hard to say which is which).

Answer (score 6):

Simplest option is that outlet F was also half-hot/half-switched and you were not aware of that, so breaking its tab (or isolating that red wire from the outlet and insulating it, if you don't want it half-switched) might fix your problem.

I would guess that you missed that in the original wiring, or it would work as expected.

Connections at B look like a switch loop out to the switch C, and the switched hot on red. The white wire in the switch loop should be re-marked with red or black tape at both ends to indicate that it is hot.

Actually, the blue connections at B look like you've got another half-switched at B, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Read our [FAQ for receptacle/switch replacements](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul).

So I gather you prefer using receptacle `A` to plug in your light.  Here came an error in logic: since you only want a split receptacle at `A`, you only broke off the tab there.  You missed the fact that receptacles `B` and `F` also had broken-off tabs.

By wiring it up as you found it *but not breaking off the tabs*, you short-circuited (literally) the switch.

Two options.

A) Break off the tabs there and `A`, `B` and `F` will have switched sockets.

Or

B) If you'd prefer to have receptacles B and F be full-hot, then you can cap off the red wire at `F`, and delete the blue pigtail at `B` which connects to a red wire.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answers seem correct.  To make this less confusing and to make the switch easier to work with, re-identify the white wire attached to the switch and also attached to the wire nut at receptacle B using black electrical tape.