# Replacing Light Switch

Tags: switch, light

I am slowly but surely replacing all the old switches in the house as many do. I am new to this and could use some advice. The switch I pulled out has two black and one red wire. I am looking for help how to wire correctly or if I have the right replacement switch or if I need something else.

[image]

Comment: the old one is 3 way switch type, the new one is 2way switch (wrong switch)

Comment: You're going to want to avail yourself of some basic house wiring knowledge before proceeding. Recognizing that as a three-way switch is fundamental. You'll also want to understand how to properly secure wires to a device screw and use wire nuts. Technique is critical to safety.

Comment: I assumed that was the case and am no expert my initial confusion came from there are no other switches that correspond with this switch. Which was odd that it would be a 3 way to no where. I will go out and pick up a 3 way switch for replacement. Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: More esoterically, be aware of the existence of 4-way switches (and UK & ex-commonwealth folks call the same switches 2-way and 3-way. respectively, to add to the potential confusion.)

Comment: How many different places is this light controlled from?  Also see this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168564/first-time-changing-switches-and-outlets-receptacles-anything-special-i-shoul

Comment: Never rely on wire color in an old house.  Get yourself a multimeter and verify hot, neutral, and ground (if present).  Also, if buying switches at the big box stores, look for commercial grade switches/outlets.   I try to buy spec grade devices.  They are usually built much better than the budget ones.  More on grades here: https://iaeimagazine.org/2005/january2005/receptacle-grades-what-do-they-mean

Answer (score 2):

The old switch was what is called a 3 way switch. Means there is another switch somewhere that switches the same light.

You need a 3 way switch, which you can identify by having 3 screws on it (not counting the ground wire)

The new one you have is just a normal 2 ways switch (2 screws).

Once you have it just use the photo to conect it correctly (duplicate the wiring)

3 observation, you have some humidity inside the wall, find out why. Second they used what is called back stab for the wires, it is recommended to use the screws. Third: we are bit concerned for your safety working with electricity, always double check the power is off, do not trust the breaker (it might be the wrong one) use an instrument to check.

As for hunting for the other 3 way switch, many of us discover it by accident or after long time. Start with what is this switch switching, then use logic where would be the other switch for that light. You might need two people, one watching the light and the other going around and activating all the switches.

Comment: I assumed that was the case and am no expert my initial confusion came from there are no other switches that correspond with this switch. Which was odd that it would be a 3 way to no where. I will go out and pick up a 3 way switch for replacement. Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: It is common that people do not know where is the other switch located, it could be in another room, up the stairs, in the kitchen and so on.

Comment: 3 observation, you have some humidity inside the wall, find out why. Second they used what is called back stab for the wires, it is recommended to use the screws. Third: we are bit concerned for yo safety working with electricity, always double check the power is off, do not trust the breaker (it might be the wrong one) use a instrument to check.